# Align elements in corners using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to put four elements in four corners of a `flex-container` using Flexbox and I'm struggling.  I can't figure out how to justify the content of individual `flex-items`. Everytime I try, it ends up putting all content of the `flex-container` either to the left or right (or top/bottom depending on the main axis).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-left">
         TL
    </div>
    <div class="top-right">
        TR
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">
        BL
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-right">
       BR
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.top-left {
 /* ? */
}

.top-right {

}

.bottom-left {

}

.bottom-right {

}
```

Here is a fiddle that illustrates what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/JWNmZ/8/

Comment: Code in your question please. Always.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Thank you for editing.  I think I did that because I just didn't have any code to add, I was just pathetically stuck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one approach for this (omitted prefixes for clarity): http://jsfiddle.net/JWNmZ/10/

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.top-left {
    flex: 50%; 
}

.top-right {
    flex: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}

.bottom-left {
    flex: 50%;
}

.bottom-right {
    flex: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Each flex item takes up 50% of the main axis, and I used `flex-wrap` to push the `.bottom-*` classes to the next row. It's quite simple, and the key is really the use of `flex-wrap`

Comment: I've found that this doesn't align the bottom items to the corners when using an arbitrary height. Here's a slight modification that does: http://jsfiddle.net/JWNmZ/25/

Comment: You just need: 
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-between;

Comment: Use `start` and `end` for Flexbox instead of `right` and `left` in case of Arabic letter right to left  (rtl),  (answer could be improved), that is main note from flexbox, as there is no more left -> right direction, only start -> end: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#Start_and_end_lines

Comment: Is this any better than the 'position: absolute' method?

Answer (score -1):

```css
        #wrapper {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: wrap row;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
#wrapper>div{
display:flex;
flex-flow:wrap column;
justify-content:space-between;
}
        .child {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: yellow;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <div class='child'></div>
            <div class='child'></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class='child'></div>
            <div class='child'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).